# Moving Azure ML predictive experiment to another tenant

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have Azure ML predictive experiment on my tenant, I just need to move it to another azure tenant.is it possible to move or copy to another tenant ?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources you should be able to move ML to another RG and also to another tenant.
You could read the details on how to move on that page too.

Hope this helps!